# Is there a way to have an "empty" environment to merely limit scope of declarations?

Tags: macros, environments, grouping

I am fairly new to LaTeX, so I apologize if this is a beginner question, but I have not found a good way to query for it otherwise.

I have observed that when I use an environment like `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`, I can place `\newcommand` inside the environment, which are scoped to the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\newcommand{\FFF}{\epsilon}

\item $\FFF$

\end{itemize}
%$\FFF$ %this is out of scope, so it would cause an error if it were commented back in.

\end{document}
```

However, environments like `itemize` and `enumerate` tend to have special effects (such as giving meaning to `\item`). My question is whether there exists an environment which has no "special effects", whose only role is to limit the scope of declarations.

Comment: You can enclose anything in braces `{...}` and this will limit the scope macro definitions within the braces.

Comment: I accept this answer if you write it as one, but just out of curiosity, does this mean all LaTeX environments come with built-in `{...}`?

Comment: @merlin2011 Essentially yes; LaTeX environments have their own scope. Anything defined (or renewed) inside of them won't be available outside of the environment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Alan Munn said, using braces is one way to go. You an also simply define your own environment:

```
\newenvironment*{dummyenv}{}{}
```

And then use it like you normally would:

```
\begin{dummyenv}
  \newcommand*{\scopedcommand}{Do stuff}
  \scopedcommand % This works
\end{dummyenv}
```

The two arguments to `newenvironment` are the code to insert before the content of the environment, and after. Leaving them blank essentially defines an environment that does nothing.

Therefore, the following won't compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}                                                 

\newenvironment*{dummyenv}{}{}                                                   

\begin{document}                                                                 
  \begin{dummyenv}                                                               
    \newcommand*{\dummycmd}{This is scoped}                                      
    \dummycmd                                                                    
  \end{dummyenv}                                                                 
  \dummycmd                                                                     
\end{document}
```

Unless you comment out the second `dummycmd`.

**EDIT:** Also, meant to say: You can also use the TeX primitives `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` for this. They form what TeX calls a 'semi-simple' group, and are not interchangeable with `{...}`.

**EDIT 2:** As @tohecz reminded me in the comments, the correct way to do this (if you really want an environment for whatever reason) is to use

```
\begin{@empty}
\end{@empty}
```

Any of the other solutions will work too, however, this is cleaner than defining a new environment.

Comment: You can use `\begin{@empty}` for this. Just remember that you cannot use `\begin{relax}` because `\relax` behaves like a non-defined thingy in these contexts ;)

Comment: @tohecz Absolutely right; I forgot all about `@empty`. I'll update the answer — thanks!

Comment: "semi-simple group"... HMMM 