# Conditional for checking if I am inside specific enviroment (tcolorbox) or macro (parbox)

Tags: conditionals

In similar problem as this ([Condition "if within another command" in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448430/condition-if-within-another-command-in-latex)), I want to define a command which would change its behavior if it occurs within the scope of another enviroment or macro. More specifically, I want to do this for tcolorbox and parbox.

In simplified version of my problem, I want to create a command like this

```
\newcommand{\sp}[1] IF WITHIN \tcolorbox{} >>> {\it #1} 
                    IF WITHIN \parbox{}        {\bf #1}
                    ELSE>               {\underline #1}
```

which would print italic text if used inside tcolorbox, bold text if used inside parbox, and underlined text elsewhere.

However, my problem is that I do not know how to set a conditional (or conditionals) that would check if we are inside tcolorbox or parbox. I tried various things that I found on this site, but to no avail, which is why I am asking you for help.

Comment: Do you want to check against nested constructs?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it is not needed, as I do not have any case of tcolorbox inside tcolorbox, parbox inside parbox, parbox inside tcolorbox or tcolorbox inside parbox

Comment: tcolorbox is an environment. `\parbox` is not an environment but is a macro used for placing things into a vertical box, outgoing from internal vertical mode.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I will correct the title and text.

Comment: Feel free to make additional edits if you think they are necessary

Comment: I mentioned the circumstance that `\parbox` is not an environment because within an environment you can check the definition of the macro `\@currenvir`. That macro expands to the name of the innermost surrounding environment. As `\parbox` is not an environment, checking `\@currenvir` is not an option here.

Comment: In such case, do you think that wrapping the \parbox in an environment that does nothing (something like defined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99797/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-empty-environment-to-merely-limit-scope-of-declarati) could be used as a workaround?

Comment: Other way around (environment inside parbox) is also acceptable.